# No bootable device found after ubuntu install Aspire ES 14

Tags: boot, uefi, laptop, acer

I just got this Acer Aspire ES14 and wanted to throw some debian based distro on it. After many attempts I still cant get it to work.

Install seems to go just fine no problems (from USB) after it tells me to reboot I get the 'No Bootable Device'.

After googling for a bit I found a couple of solutions

Dont use UEFI but legacy mode -> not an option in my BIOS

Select a UEFI file of some sorts -> Cant do that either, only options are 'Erase all secure boot setting' and 'Restore Default'

Enable/disable secure boot -> tried both, same results

If somebody could help me I would be so gratefull, I'm getting desparate.

Link  to boot repair utility [here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25284232)

Comment: does your system have OS boot options or only device boot options?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I guess you mean in the boot priority whether it says the device or the os? In that case i can only choose the device from which to boot.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from the Ubuntu installer booted in its "try before installing" mode and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: [link](paste.ubuntu.com/25284232) I want to install the os on the emmc drive not on the the hard disk

Answer (score 0):

Device boot requires the default media path - */efi/boot/bootx64.efi* in the ESP partition order to boot.
So copy */efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi* to */efi/boot/* and rename to *bootx64.efi*.
If you are using secure boot, */efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi* will need to be copied and renamed.
Note: you will need to temporarily remove the ESP flag in order to make this change.

Comment: Sadly enough I still get the 'No Bootable Device'

Comment: maybe case sensitive .. try EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi. I have also seen some systems require a recovery partition to be first. a small ntfs partition flagged as system reserved or recovery

Comment: Tried both, still nothing though.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Installing and then changing to Legacy mode didn't work. Boot Repair utility didn't work. Manually selecting (in the BIOS) a .efi file didn't work...

We finally solved the following way:

1. Go to BIOS (F2) and in the Boot menu, change Boot mode from UEFI to Legacy
2. Install Ubuntu from a pen drive normally.

This is for an Ubuntu-only installation. No dual boot in our case.

Comment: All Acer need to have latest UEFI from Acer and then set "trust" for UEFI boot files. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & Acer Very latest UEFI/BIOS works, downgrade not required if no trust screens, you must now upgrade:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141